# Excel - Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057') The index into the specified collection is out of bounds

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I have run successfully in Excel for the past two years but continue to get the following message on my latest project:

> "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057') The index into the specified collection is out of bounds".

I am referencing more shapes than I have done in previous iterations (204 shapes in file) but not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.  The macro follows:

```
Sub MapMacro()

    For i = 5 To 207
    Range("actReg").Value = Range("A" & i).Value

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Variables" Then
        Worksheets("Map").Activate
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Range("actReg").Value).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("actRegCode").Value).Interior.Color

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Map" Then
        Worksheets("Variables").Activate
    End If

    Next i

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What line does the code show an error for when you stop and go to the debugger?

Comment: "ActiveSheet.Shapes(Range("actReg").Value).Select" is highlighted in the Debugger.  Is there a good way to add/share the file or is that discouraged?

Comment: Perhaps `Range("actRegCode").Value` should be `Range("actRegCode").Address`

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately changing to "Range("actRegCode").Address" yields the exact same result

Comment: File is here if of benefit:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0x703p1njz4pwdd/Run-time%20error%20%27-2147024809%20%2880070057%27%29.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Issue solved - the shapes were named as numbers but because there are only 205 actual shapes, the "name" must be less than 205, hence 211 which is the first name after the limit is where the error occurs.  Fixed by renaming all the shapes to include verbiage...thanks for assistance